# Are there any plans to port the old indicators for the new gnome panel?

Tags: indicator, gnome-panel

In ubuntu 11.04, I was using the classic desktop and have all Ubuntu indicators on the Gnome panel. But in Ubuntu 11.10 we can only use the classic gnome 3, so is there any plans to port the Ubuntu indicators for the new gnome panel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some applets are available for gnome-panel 3, but not all.
https://launchpad.net/gnome-applets

Some applets have not been ported from Gtk2 to Gtk3 yet.
Seems indicator-applet is in progress of being ported.
https://bugs.launchpad.net/indicator-applet/+bug/724369